# Divs inside a grid item?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, css-grid

I am using a Grid layout, and I am trying to place an image next to a text inside of the same griditem. The image is like an icon and supposed to be right next to the text (as it's placed in the code below). The text next to it is also supposed to have a different color and font than the rest of the text. I previously tried this with a span. However, when I use any of those tags inside the griditem it kinda breaks the grid. Instead of being a normal wall of text, it's suddenly all next to each other. I've been trying to figure this out for a couple hours now, can anyone help?

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template: repeat(4, auto) 300px 150px / repeat(6, 1fr);
  grid-gap: 3px;
  grid-template-areas: ". . h h . ." ". . img img . ." "a a a a a a" ". t t t t ." ". p1 p2 p3 p4 ." ". sm sm hp hp .";
}

.text {
  display: flex;
  grid-area: t;
  font-size: 1vw;
  font-family: Verdana;
  border: 1px solid #3f3f3f;
  border-radius: 25px;
  padding: 2%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="text">Hi!<br><br> Just a quick note to say thank you for making an account with SuperBath.co.uk!
    <br><br> Having a SuperBath.co.uk account will give you the following perks:<br>
    <br>
    <img src="..scratches/Drop.jpg">Saved personal details<br> Personal data is instantly available as you log in with your email address and password. <br><br>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I'd also recommend using proper text elements like paragraphs and spans to hold the text and avoid using break tags for spacing.

Comment: you're right, I copied the wrong code

Comment: i did edit the code

Comment: When I use proper <p> it does the same thing - paragraphs are displayed next to each other in the grid item instead of properly one below the other.

Comment: What is the final result supposed to look like...my initial suggestion would be to remove `display:flex` from the div.

Comment: That doesn't change anything. 
My problem is basically that whenever I use a tag that sections the grid item in any way, such as span, or img or even p, instead of being displayed properly, the text now goes sideways, each paragraph being next to each other.

Comment: This has nothing to do with CSS Grid...but as I said try removing `display:flex` from the `.text` div. Until we know what this is supposed to look like it's hard to help.

Comment: it is supposed to look like this: https://imgur.com/5B9ML4v
but it looks like that: https://imgur.com/KyikWqR

Comment: So...have you removed the `display:flex` from that div....that should do it.

Comment: Yea  I have.. I told you it doesn't change anything ;)

Comment: Then demo that....becuase it should.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/ynt3o53d/1/

Answer (score 1):

The main problem here is that because you use `display: flex` on `text`, the `img` becomes a flex *row* item and the text before and after the image, will become anonymous flex items, hence they line up side-by-side.

There is mainly two ways to solve that, where one solution is to wrap the whole text/image chunk in a `span`, and then, to enable a different color on the text next to the `img`, also wrap it with a `span`.

Stack snippet

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template: repeat(4, auto) 300px 150px / repeat(6, 1fr);
  grid-gap: 3px;
  grid-template-areas: ". . h h . ." ". . img img . ." "a a a a a a" ". t t t t ." ". p1 p2 p3 p4 ." ". sm sm hp hp .";
}

.text {
  display: flex;
  grid-area: t;
  font-size: 1vw;
  font-family: Verdana;
  border: 1px solid #3f3f3f;
  border-radius: 25px;
  padding: 2%;
}

.text span span {
  color: blue                   /*  added  */
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="text"><span>Hi!
    <br>
    <br> Just a quick note to say thank you for making an account with SuperBath.co.uk!
    <br>
    <br> Having a SuperBath.co.uk account will give you the following perks:
    <br>
    <br>
    <img src="http://placehold.it/15/00f"><span>Saved personal details</span>
    <br> Personal data is instantly available as you log in with your email address and password.
    <br>
    <br></span>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

Or as suggested in a comment, simply remove `display: flex` from the `text`, and only wrap the text that should have different color with a `span`.

Stack snippet

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template: repeat(4, auto) 300px 150px / repeat(6, 1fr);
  grid-gap: 3px;
  grid-template-areas: ". . h h . ." ". . img img . ." "a a a a a a" ". t t t t ." ". p1 p2 p3 p4 ." ". sm sm hp hp .";
}

.text {
  grid-area: t;
  font-size: 1vw;
  font-family: Verdana;
  border: 1px solid #3f3f3f;
  border-radius: 25px;
  padding: 2%;
}

.text span {
  color: blue                   /*  added  */
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="text">Hi!
    <br>
    <br> Just a quick note to say thank you for making an account with SuperBath.co.uk!
    <br>
    <br> Having a SuperBath.co.uk account will give you the following perks:
    <br>
    <br>
    <img src="http://placehold.it/15/00f"><span>Saved personal details</span>
    <br> Personal data is instantly available as you log in with your email address and password.
    <br>
    <br>
  </div>
</div>
```